# How to add text converting button in android studio

Tags: android, admob

I had placed adMob ads in my android application. Now I'm watching an Ad unit on which the following line is written.

```
Congratulations! You are displaying an adMob Ad
```

There is no real ad appearing. Anyone tell me is this ok or not?? will I get money for these ads or not?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get paid showing test Ads. AdMob shows test Ads if you are using an emulator or if you have added your device as a test device. It also shows test Ads if you are using the test Ad Unit ID it provides in document.

Check your code to see if your have [enabled test Ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/targeting#test_ads):

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
        .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
        .build();
```

Comment: means i will not get money until i upload it to playstore??

Comment: Correct, they don't want people making bots that just open up a test app and click the ads all day.

Comment: @JawadAdil You need to publish your app to the public to make money from showing Ads. If you spam clicks on the Ads by yourself, Google will know it and will ban you from showing anymore Ads or disable your AdMob account. Here is the AdMob Policies for reference: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en